# How to get radio name value from class referance angular 2

Tags: angular

```
<div class="GuessWho">
    <input checked="checked" id="radio1" name="optradio" type="radio" value="0"> 
    <label class="radio-inline labtxt" for="radio1">Hans Zimmer</label> 
    <input id="radio2" name="optradio" type="radio" value="0"> 
    <label class="radio-inline labtxt" for="radio2">Ramin Djawadi</label> 
    <input id="radio3" name="optradio" type="radio" value="1"> 
    <label class="radio-inline labtxt" for="radio3">A.R. Rahman</label>
</div>

<a class="btn btn-success" (click)="guessWho()">Submit</a>
```

Guess Who is dynamically generated in `[innerHTML]="funDetails?.LongDescription | safeHtml"`

So, how do I get value of checked radio input, after click on submit button in angular 2 `(value==1 is right answer otherwise fail)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use FormGroup to bind model with form. for eg :

**Component.ts**

```
myForm: FormGroup;
ngOnInit() {
    this.addhtmltoform(model);
}
addhtmltoform(model: GuessWhoViewModel) {
    this.myFormOrganization = this.fb.group(
        {
            optradio: [model.optradio]

        });
}

guessWhoSave(data: GuessWhoViewModel) {
//Here you will get the value of optradio
    this._myService.guessWhoSave(data).subscribe();
}
```

**Component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="guessWhoSave(myForm.value)">    
<div class="GuessWho">
<input checked="checked" id="radio1" name="optradio" formControlName="optradio" type="radio" value="0"> 
<label class="radio-inline labtxt" for="radio1">Hans Zimmer</label> 
<input id="radio2" name="optradio" formControlName="optradio" type="radio" value="0"> 
<label class="radio-inline labtxt" for="radio2">Ramin Djawadi</label> 
<input id="radio3" name="optradio" formControlName="optradio" type="radio" value="1"> 
<label class="radio-inline labtxt" for="radio3">A.R. Rahman</label>
</div>

<a class="btn btn-success" (click)="guessWhoSave()">Submit</a>
</form>
```

formControlName will automatically handle the two way binding and you will get the value of optradio in guessWhoSave() method

Comment: any library needed for that??

Comment: I am getting error     **ERROR ReferenceError: model is not defined**

Comment: its old database dynamic render form so we canot write formControlName inside input but we can write out side GuessWho div <FORM>

Answer (score 0):

Write below code in html file

```
<form ngNativeValidate class="form-horizontal" #addForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="addUser(addForm.value)">
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-12 control-label">User Type</label>
    <div class="i-checks">
        <label class="lbl-bb-qa"> 
            <input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="userType" value="0" name="userType" required> <i></i> userType1
        </label>
        <label class="lbl-sml-qa"> 
            <input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="userType" checked="" value="1" name="userType" required> <i></i> userType2
        </label>
        <label class="lbl-both-qa"> 
            <input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="userType" checked="" value="2" name="userType" required> <i></i> userType3
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
        <button type="submit" class="btn-danger">Add User</button>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Access value of radio button in .ts file using

```
var user_type = formData.userType
```

Comment: In the form we can not write  [(ngModel)]="userType"  its dynamically render from old database but we can add <form >  </form > out side div